# Add Number of days column to Date Column in same dataframe for Spark Scala App

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dateadd

I have a `dataframe` df of `columns` `("id", "current_date", "days")` and I am trying to add the the "`days`" to "`current_date`" and create a new `dataframe` with new `column` called "`new_date`" using spark scala function `date_add()`

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("new_Date", date_add(df("current_date"), df("days").cast("Int")))
```

But looks like the function `date_add` only accepts `Int` values and not `columns`. How can get the desired output in such case? Are there any alternative functions i can use to get the desired output?

spark version: 1.6.0
scala version: 2.10.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small custom udf can be used to make this date arithmetic possible.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat    

val date_add = udf((x: String, y: Int) => {
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val result = new Date(sdf.parse(x).getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(y))
  sdf.format(result)
} )
```

**Usage**:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, "2017-01-01", 10), (2, "2017-01-01", 20)).toDF("id", "current_date", "days")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, current_date: string, days: int]

scala> df.withColumn("new_Date", date_add($"current_date", $"days")).show()
+---+------------+----+----------+
| id|current_date|days|  new_Date|
+---+------------+----+----------+
|  1|  2017-01-01|  10|2017-01-11|
|  2|  2017-01-01|  20|2017-01-21|
+---+------------+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 19):

No need to use an UDF, you can do it using an SQL expression:

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("new_date", expr("date_add(current_date,days)"))
```

Comment: you can even skip `expr` and directly use (in spark 2.1+) 
`val newDF = df.withColumn("new_date", date_add($"current_date",days))`

Comment: I haven't found a way of making this syntax (`val newDF = df.withColumn("new_date", date_add($"current_date",days))`) work. As of today, in Spark 2.2, the only options I can make work are a UDF or `expr()` (and I prefer the UDF). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222781/use-existing-column-in-date-add-spark-function?noredirect=1#comment87463581_50222781 for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but when I'm trying the code you mentioned above column is generating but the values in it are null. here is piece of code. `val dt3 = dt2.withColumn("new_date", expr("date_add('Week Start',dummy)"))` could you please help me with this.