# Passing arguments to a Scala udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am calling a udf on a specific column of my dataframe, in which I check if all values are valid as per a specified date format.

```
sourcefile = sourcefile.withColumn(column, DateConversion(col(column)))
```

Here DateConversion is my udf. My question here is that, is there a way  by which I can pass the valid date format "yyyy/MM/dd" as a string to this udf which can be used internally in the udf for validation purposes.

I was trying

```
sourcefile = sourcefile.withColumn(column, DateConversion(col(column),"yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

But this gives and error.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361332/add-number-of-days-column-to-date-column-in-same-dataframe-for-spark-scala-app) will give you a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just curry the udf, passing in the date format - or really any other argument you want - when the udf is created.

```
def getUdf(format: String) = udf{date: String =>
  /*some logic that uses format*/}
```

And then call that method like so

```
val dateConversion = getUdf("yyyy/MM/dd")
sourcefile = sourcefile.withColumn(column, dateConversion(col(column)))
```

This will also allow you to easily swap out the date conversion format, by changing the argument passed to getUdf, rather than the difficulty if the format is hardcoded inside the udf

Answer (score 6):

You can use lit function to create a literal column and pass to the udf.

```
def udfName = udf((name: String, value:String) => {
      name + value
    })
```

Use `lit()` function while calling udf:

```
dataframe.withColumn("colName", udfName($"firstName", lit("xyz")))
```