# how can I pass two columns of my dataframe - date and days to date_add function?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

My data frame has two columns - `start_date` and `duration`.

How can I use `date_add` function to create a derived column end_date?

Comment: you got the duration on hours ? on seconds ?
can you tell us how your start_date looks like.

Comment: start date looks like 1998-04-05 07:27:31 (string) and the duration is in seconds (string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Number of days column to Date Column in same dataframe for Spark Scala App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361332/add-number-of-days-column-to-date-column-in-same-dataframe-for-spark-scala-app)