# Spark Scala Dataframe Column mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This works fine on a DF.

```
val recs = spark.table("IIR").select($"dateFrom").withColumn("N", lit(5))
val rec2 = recs.withColumn("sellByDate", date_add(col("dateFrom"), 5))
```

However, this does not:

```
val rec2 = recs.withColumn("sellByDate", date_add(col("dateFrom"), $"N"))
```

The infamous message is gotten:

```
notebook:11: error: type mismatch;
  found   : String("$N")
  required: Int
```

What is the easiest away around this?

Comment: OK, will look but as soon as dates and Cols, a bit of a muddle.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that with support for literals, columns and strings, number of possible signatures grows like crazy. Oh, and it goes without saying that you should ignore the accepted answer and go straight to [`expr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368970/10465355).

Comment: That worked like a beaut, thanks. Should have thought about expr. Indeed.